# Cocoapods error submitting an Xcode project archive

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, cocoapods, provisioning-profile

I can run my cocoapods enabled project as debug build, and create an archive.

But when I try to upload the archive to the app store, I get the errors below.

What I already did:

- Update cocoa pods to latest version
- Run pod install
- Create and install new production certificate
- Create and install new app store distribution provisioning profile.

Xcode 6.0.1 
Cocoapods 0.34.1

No idea what is going on.

IDEDistribution.critical.log is empty. (?)

IDEDistribution.verbose.log has this warning:

```
[OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2c140d870:'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a'>
```

The first error showing up in IDEDistribution.standard.log is "No UUID for libPods.a". (Truncated for readability - complete file [here](http://ts-dropzone.s3.amazonaws.com/IDEDistribution.standard.log)):

```
2014-10-08 14:29:23 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: MyAppName, task: Submit
2014-10-08 14:29:23 +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x7fb2ba8a23f0>
2014-10-08 14:29:24 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2c140d870:'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a'>: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2c140d870:'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a'>" UserInfo=0x7fb2c3187430 {NSLocalizedDescription=Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2c140d870:'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a'>}
2014-10-08 14:29:24 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2c140d870:'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo=0x7fb2c31876a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2014-10-08 14:29:24 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find embedded provisioning profile for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2c140d870:'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Can't find an embedded provisioning profile. Not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2c140d870:'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a'>" UserInfo=0x7fb2c31880e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Can't find an embedded provisioning profile. Not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb2c140d870:'/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-10-08/MyAppName 08-10-14 16.29.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/libPods.a'>}
2014-10-08 14:29:26 +0000 [MT] Proceeding to distribution step IDEDistributionDryRunPackagingStepViewController, context: <IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fb2c1665180; archive(resolved)='<IDEArchive: 0x7fb2ba412ce0>', distributionTask(resolved)='1', distributionMethod(resolved)='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x7fb2ba8a23f0>', teamID(resolved)='1234567890'>
Chain (4, self inclusive):
<IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fb2c1665180; archive = '(null)', distributionMethod='(null)', teamID='(null)'>
<IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fb2c07cf3e0; archive = '(null)', distributionMethod='(null)', teamID='(null)'>
<IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fb2c2cb8d90; archive = '(null)', distributionMethod='(null)', teamID='1234567890'>
<IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fb2bd686c90; archive = '<IDEArchive: 0x7fb2ba412ce0>', distributionMethod='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x7fb2ba8a23f0>', teamID='(null)'>

...

2014-10-08 14:29:34 +0000  Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/symbols '-noTextInSOD' '-noDaemon' '-arch' 'all' '-symbolsPackageDir' '/var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.ngq/Symbols' '/var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.ngq/libPods.a'
2014-10-08 14:29:35 +0000  error: No UUID for /var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.ngq/libPods.a(Pods-dummy.o)
error: No UUID for /var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.ngq/libPods.a(Pods-dummy.o)
error: No UUID for /var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.ngq/libPods.a(Pods-dummy.o)
2014-10-08 14:29:35 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/symbols exited with 1ibPods.a [armv7, 0.001058 seconds]:
/var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.ngq/libPods.a [arm64, 0.001058 seconds]:
/var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.ngq/libPods.a [armv7s, 0.001058 seconds]:

2014-10-08 14:29:35 +0000  Step failed: <IDEDistributionSymbolsStep: 0x7fb2c2a8e640>

...

2014-10-08 14:29:37 +0000 [MT] Submission failed for archive MyAppName with issues:
(
"<IDEDistributionIssue: severity(error), error(Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-20008 \"The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive.  Please make sure /var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.FM2/MyAppName.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive.\" UserInfo=0x7fb2c33e57d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive.  Please make sure /var/folders/_9/kqpqwtj16mn3r6xzf3kcj3w80000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.FM2/MyAppName.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.})>"
```

As always, any help or pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Strange. Normally libPods.a is not inside the .app file. Looks like it tries to locate it there. Can you try using `pod update`, then Xcode clean and upload again?

Comment: After pod update, Xcode full clean, created archive - same error.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of header search path under build settings?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: @Justin Did you get any solution to this issue ?